# Is there any logcat library/framework for android?

Tags: android, logcat

Is there any library for logcat viewing logs , getting logs especially?I do not need an complicated one .I just need when a new log occurs it notifies me.

Comment: You mean aside from the SDK supplied `adb logcat`?  What does that not do that you need?

Comment: Yes,i mean aside from SDK.adb logcat is not programicaly.I need something that keep reading logs and when something occuer (lets say an exception) it notifies me.I found something https://github.com/androidnerds/logger but its not what i want (has no notifies etc.). I am trying to add notify feature to it.

Comment: Ah alright, I think we may have some language barrier issues here unfortunately.  `adb logcat` is certainly "programmatic".  You could easily write a service that connects to it and notifies you of certain activity.  From the project you linked, it sounds like what you're really looking for is a library that runs on the device itself and notifies you of certain activity?  If that's the case, I think the project you linked is a good start.  You will probably just need to combine it with some code to send you an email, or however else you want to be notified.